# Node.js file not found, issue with my path format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filepath

I'm working on a node.js application to interact with the Twilio API. I have a problem getting my files to associate in the way I expected. My file directory structure looks like this
myapproot

-public
---form.js
-routes
---index.js
-views
---index.html
-app.js
-config.js
-server.js

In index.html, I conclude the page with the following script declaration:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/form.js"></script>
```

But when I load up the page, I get the following error:

```
GET: http://localhost:1337/public/form.js 404 (not found)
```

If I follow the path-link provided by VS code, it shows that js file, but it's not getting loaded into my view. Is there a mistake with my path declaration?

Comment: this is clearly a routing problem, but you've provided no information about your router or webserver. vscode doesn't read your router to know how it should link to files, you have to do that yourself. That is most certainly the wrong path.

Comment: You're right. It was an issue with how I was routing in code I didn't provide. Sorry!

Comment: You can edit your post to give the routing code or provide an answer on your own, when you have solved the issue.

Comment: You may not realize, but node.js serves NO files by default (unlike some other web server infrastructures).  It will only serve a file to the browser if you configure a route for that file in your node.js server code.  So, for us to help you, we must see your node.js server routing code to see what you have so far and what we would recommend to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, what that command is doing is this:

```
<script type = 'Text/JavaScript' src = 'http://localhost:1337/public/form.js'>
```

So, what I'd suggest that you try is to set up the server-side code to handle requests to that directory on your server.